# cant add mutiple markers on map - leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

OK so using leaflet.js
I can't add multiple markers

```
const L = window.L;
L.LocUtil = {
  locToCoords: (t, e) => {
    var i = L.Projection.SphericalMercator,
      n = t.loc1,
      o = t.loc2;
    e.switchedCoords && (o = [n, (n = o)][0]);
    var r = {
      x: (n - e.dx) / e.kx,
      y: (o - e.dy) / e.ky,
    };
    return i.unproject(r);
  },
};
var map = L.map("map").setView([0, 0], 1.5);

map.zoomControl.remove();
L.tileLayer(
  "https://maps.izurvive.com/maps/CH-Sat/1.17.0/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  {
    tms: !0,
    minZoom: 1,
    noWrap: !0,
    bounds: L.latLngBounds([-85, -180], [85, 180]),
  }
).addTo(map);

var locations = [
  ["LOC 1", 4893.43, 9813.06],
  ["LOC 2", 4022.35, 9046.96],
];
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new L.circleMarker([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]], {
    weight: 5,
    color: "blue",
    fillColor: "blue",
    fillOpacity: 0.25,
    radius: 2,
  })
    .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
    .addTo(map);
}
```

Now the circleMarker works when I just specify 1 location without using the arrayhowever I tried adding multiple lat/long inside array and the map is loading just no makers being added

Comment: The markers are getting added to the map - just not to the visible area. Given that you're doing a game map (DayZ, from the looks of it) with a cartesian coordinate system, you should read https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html

Comment: I got it working with 1 marker here .. 
https://chrisyates.uk/bountybot/test.html
but cant add multiple using array like outlined above

Comment: In your 1-marker example, you're running the coordinates through your `LocUtils.locToCoords` function. In your multiple-marker example, you're not. Note that using `L.CRS.Simple` would simplify your code, as you wouldn't need such a function since the coordinate systems would match better.